# Get data from DIV

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I'm trying to get data from several div and post with ajax all data to PHP function

```
<div id="1" class="structure_box span12 strow_0 ">
    <div class="structuretmp_name span6">
        <span>name</span>
    </div>
    <div id="structuretmp_list" class="structuretmp_list span6">
        <select id="jform_structuretmp" class="chzn-done" name="jform[structuretmp]" style="display: none;">
            <div id="jform_structuretmp_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 220px;"
                 title="">
                <a class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
                    <span>Age</span>
                    <div>
                        <div class="chzn-drop">
                        </div>
                        ...
                        //several item like this
```

I need something like this to pass php file as a json or object
name:NAME,age:birthday,,,
that for example name is a span and NAME is chosen field from chosen plugin

EDIT :

The script

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit").click(function(){

                    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
                        data: {
                            id: id,
                            org_name: org_name,
                            ...
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(result){
                        alert(result);

                     });

                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: This got upvoted? What have you tried?

Comment: Please add more details and some of your existing Code and specify your question: Which Data do you want to send? Do you need to organize/ convert it? How does your PHP look ?

Comment: So in the end you want to post a json object containing id etc. from your html code to a php site, do you want to send all objects ore just specific ones ? what information do you want to post ? all attributes and the innerText or just some attributes ? no innerText innerText ? What is org_name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data-id attribute for put your id something like in base DIV

```
data-id="YOUR ID"
```

and Specific name to base div for read each inner div and span

```
 name="base"
```

finnaly u can easily read all data with :

```
   var base=jQuery('[name="base"]');
for (var i=0;i<base.length;j++)
        {

            obj = {id: jQuery(base[i]).attr('data-id')};

        }
```

and also u can pass data with JSON

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'WHERE EVER YOU WANT',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                data
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {

                return true;
            },
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                if (result == 'error')
                    return false;

                return true;
            },

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

if you just want the text, use `.text();`

```
var divContent = $('div').text();
```

and replace the 'div' with your div ID or Class

So in your case, it would be:

```
var age = $('.chzn-single span').text();
```

I would recommend giving your spans/items a class so you can call them directly.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_get

Comment: I dont think that is what he wanted

Comment: he needs to be more clear then... pretty sure he wants to be able to post data from within divs. EG with a div having a class of age: data: { age : $('.age').text(); .........

Comment: I think he wants to grab the data and some attributes from unknown divs ... but i hope he updates his question soon its a bit broad

Comment: @jake and Johannes Geidel thankyou for your help but i just needed post dynamic data with ajax

Comment: by dynamic, do you mean the elements will change? or they will be entered and submitted? by the looks of it, you have a submit button, which can trigger your ajax. within that ajax, you can get the .text of an element, or if its an input, you can also use .val() http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_html_set